# Public transport offline routing

Tags: software-recommendations, routing, transportation, ios, offline

Is it possible to make offline public transport routing? What services should I use and what steps are? I'm developing in iOS platform.

Comment: Your question is too broad, you need to narrow down the scope. And yes it is definitely possible.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend having a look at the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/), it supports fully offline routing and geocoding.  Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/tree/master/OfflineRoutingSample) from their GitHub page.  They have samples in both Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: @crmackey are you sure public transport routes are available in this service? don't find any confirmations on their site.

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail when I read your post.  You can do this with public transport routing, you would just need to build the network yourself.  In the sample I posted, Esri has created a network for the streets of San Francisco and published it as a tile package.

Comment: @crmackey thanks, just built the sample but haven't no idea how to build public transport routing in it. Could you give some links, what I services I should investigate etc.? :-)

Comment: I just added an answer that has some links.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments, I would recommend having a look at the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/), it supports fully offline routing and geocoding. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/tree/master/OfflineRoutingSample/swift) from their GitHub page. They have samples in both Swift and Objective-C.

You will have to build the public transportation network yourself, but maybe you can find shapefiles/feature classes on line for the public transit for a starting point.  This part requires having access to ArcGIS software and the Network Analyst extension.  Here is how to set up a [network dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm), and here is how to [add routing capabilities](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/route-tutorial.htm) to that network dataset.

And actually after a [quick google search](https://ting.com/blog/ting-tip-for-ios-download-google-maps-for-offline-use/), looks like google maps has added [offline support](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/6291838?hl=en) that can be used in iOS too, so this may be a better option.  However, I do not know if they will have the public transportation networks you're looking for.